# There is no infinite descending chain of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm currently reading a set theory book and it uses the fact that

> There is not infinite descending chain of ordinals.

But I can't find the proof. (And also I remember Topology by Munkres uses this fact somewhere) 
I don't know how to prove this. May I get a help?

Comment: It would be strange if your set theory book did not prove this fact. It's equivalent to the well-ordering of the ordinals. (Note that there is no set of ordinals, otherwise this set would be a transitive well-ordered set and would be a member of itself, contradicting the fact that transitive well-orders have a unique embedding into itself, even if the axiom of foundation is not present.)

Comment: I didn't realize it is equivalent to the well-ordering of the ordinals. Thx!

Comment: What is your definition of the ordinals?

Comment: @user21820 Strictly speaking that's not right - the hard part of showing that the ordinals are well-ordered is showing that they are *linearly ordered*. A set (or class) can be well-founded (=no descending sequences) without being well-ordered (linearly ordered + well-founded).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Alright alright I was assuming as given that ordinals were linearly ordered and so proof-morally what I stated is right. In any case strictly speaking all valid sentences over any theory are equivalent, so what are we talking about? =D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we have a decreasing sequence of ordinals $\alpha_0>\alpha_1>. . $. Recall that this means that $\alpha_{i+1}\in\alpha_i$. Then $\alpha_0$ is not well-ordered under $\in$, since $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . .$ is a $\in$-descending sequence of elements of $\alpha_0$. But by definition, an ordinal is a transitive set which is well-ordered by $\in$, so this is a contradiction.

(Note that it is significantly harder to show that the ordinals are *linearly* ordered - that is, that given distinct ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, either $\alpha\in\beta$ or $\beta\in\alpha$. But if all you want is that there are no descending sequences, then this is straightforward.)

Comment: Are you saying there is no least element of $a_0$ and so it is not well-ordered?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yes: from the assumption that there is a decreasing sequence of ordinals, we get that some ordinal $\alpha_0$ is not well-ordered by $\in$, but this is impossible so we're done.

Comment: For anyone else reading this years later, additional context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_ordinal

Answer (score 4):

[Well ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) means that a non-empty subset has a least element. Now if there were an infinite descending chain $... a_2 < a_1 < a_0$, then there would be a non-empty subset $\{ ...,a_2,a_1,a_0\}$ which doesn't have a least element. Contradiction.